# Enterprise Apps for Non-enterprise Class Clients?

Tags: iphone

I have a question about enterprise apps for the iPhone. A client would like me to develop an app for her that should not appear on the iStore, but they do not meet the qualifications for an enterprise app. They would like to use the app in their organization on multiple devices without reinstalling it every time the provisioning profile expires (or paying the $100 developer fee every year). Does anyone have experience with this sort of issue, or any suggestions that might address their concerns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no silver bullets here. The options for distribution are:

- App Store
- Ad hoc
- Enterprise

Only the fourth option would allow you to avoid the developer program fee:

- Jailbreak

Of course I wouldn't recommend this for use in the enterprise.

Comment: Apple won't make exceptions to the enterprise requirements, will they?

Comment: Unlikely, but I guess there's no harm in asking.